# How can I find out the number of seconds since 1970 using DateTime in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently using this code:

```
 var stringSecsNow = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds.ToString();
```

But is there some other way. I seem to recall in another language that there was an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost same but looks easier.

```
DateTime PreviousDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
var stringSecsNow = (DateTime.UtcNow - PreviousDateTime).TotalSeconds.ToString();
```